# Changing input value once assigned

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuex

I am in a confusing situation, I am assigning a value to input element, from route param

```
<input type="search" class="form-control search-control" :value="search">
```

And the search computed function

```
computed: {
  search() {
    if(this.serviceBenefitRoute) {
      return this.serviceBenefitRoute;
    }
    return this.$store.state.search;
  }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that when `this.serviceBenefitRoute` has a value it gets shown in input box but it cannot be deleted, it keeps staying, I try to remove but it comes back again. I am stuck with this problem for quite long and running out of ideas.

Comment: why not using a computed variable?

Comment: the issue should be caused by `:value="search"`, you bind the value, but never change the value of data property=search. probably you should use `v-model="search"`

Comment: It is a computed variable, and I tried using v-model as well

Comment: When the value in your `<input>` is changed, what should happen? Where should the new value be stored?

Comment: you can add `console.log(this.serviceBenefitRoute, this.$store.state.search)` into the computed property=search, then check whether the value is expected or always is same.

Comment: Well, the `<input>` is not changed, I just need to be able to remove the default value that comes from `this.$route.params.service` right now, the value of `this.$route.params.service` cannot be deleted at all once it's appended, but if there is no value for `this.$route.params.service` we have no problem, it behaves similar to a normal input value

Comment: _"Deleted"_ **is changed**. Please describe **in your question** what it is you're trying to achieve

Comment: Just like when I type into this comment box, I can delete what I type right? But if the comment box has already something written on it (obtained from route param in my context) it cannot be deleted and typed something new

Comment: @zuif is that what you **want** to happen or what **is** happening? Again, please **edit your question** to describe what it is you **want** to happen

Comment: @zuif, you should try the solution Phil already answered first, it should meet your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to set the **initial** value of `search` first from your route, then falling back to your store.

You should be able to use this

```
data () {
  return {
    search: this.$route.params.service || this.$store.state.search
  }
}
```

and then use `v-model`

```
<input type="search"
       class="form-control search-control" 
       v-model="search">
```

You do not need a computed value for `search`.

Comment: But I already have that defined `serviceBenefitRoute: this.$route.params.service, `

Comment: @zuif very confusing. Could you please answer [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50847719/changing-input-value-once-assigned/50847953#comment88699163_50847719) on your question then

Comment: But how can I check for the v-model from `this.$route.params.service` as well ?

Comment: @zuif it's best if you describe what it is you're trying to do. Your question speaks only of symptoms

Comment: @zuif I've updated my answer with what I _think_ you're trying to achieve

Comment: Thank you, such a simple fix !